# Tiling a 2D Texture to Fill a Rectangle

Tags: xna, textures, tile

Is it possible to tile an image in XNA so that it fills the entirety of a rectangle? I've tried Googling the subject, but I can't find anything that seems to work (I'm probably missing something obvious though). I found [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975153.aspx), but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my code:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);
```

But this just stretched the texture to fill the rectangle, not tile it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wrap sampler states indicate that texture coordinates that fall outside of the normal 0-1 range will be wrapped.  If you're calling `Draw()` with a null source rectangle, then your texture coordinates are always going to be from exactly 0 to exactly 1.

Try calling `Draw()` with a source rectangle that's bigger than the texture.  Twice as big should tile it twice, four times as big should tile it four times, etc.

Comment: Thanks man. This seems a little unintuitive, but it works so I'm happy with it!