# How to cheaply draw a repeating pattern over rectangular area?

Tags: xna, textures, repeat, rectangles

I have small textures (8×8, 16×16, 20×20, also 10×20, 24×32, 64×16 and other various sizes) which I'd like to fill a certain rectangular area on the screen, repeating and not stretching.

Problem is if I just draw enough sprites one after another by doing multiple draw calls, it just consumes a lot of cpu. Isn't there some other way to do it that wouldn't require so many draw calls?

Using pre-made textures of repeating sprites isn't a solution — target rectangular areas have different sizes and are randomly generated each game.

Comment: @JasonD Texture2d, draw to fill rectangles in a repeating pattern.

Comment: This is a rather common question; see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313388/xna-tiling-a-2d-texutre-to-fill-a-rectangle/7314105#7314105).

Answer (score 0):

At the time you create your random rectangular areas you could create a RenderTarget2D along with each rectangle. Then you draw your tiles into that RenderTarget2D once. After that you could use the RenderTarget2D (which can be drawn just like a Texture2D) to draw ALL your tiles in a single Draw call.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that I do have to make a lot of draw calls, which I am trying to avoid, and I successfully have with an answer provided by Cole Campbell in a comment above.