# Scaling an object in XNA and tiling the texture as it scales

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, 3ds

I'm making a game using C#/XNA 4.0.

So I have a simple box I made in 3DSMax

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgXcl.png

And I scale it

```
Vector3 scaleVector = new Vector3(width, 1, height); 
Matrix newMatrix = scale * translationMatrix;
```

here is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApoAB.png

Here is my rendering methods:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draws an objects with the specified texture. This DOES change the current textures, so be careful!
    /// </summary>
    public static void DrawModel(GraphicsDevice gd, Model model,
        RenderTechnique technique, Vector3 cameraPosition,
        Matrix world, Matrix viewProjection, LightList lights, Texture2D texture)
    {
        SetTexture(texture, model);
        DrawModel(gd, model, technique, cameraPosition, world, viewProjection, lights);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a texture for a model by changing the effect parameters
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetTexture(Texture2D texture, Model model)
    {
        // for each mesh in model
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            // for each mesh part
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                // if primitives to change
                if (meshPart.PrimitiveCount > 0)
                {
                    // set texture visa effect
                    Effect effect = meshPart.Effect;
                    effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(texture);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Main Draw method. All draw calls end up here eventually.
    /// </summary>
    public static void DrawModel(GraphicsDevice gd, Model model,
        RenderTechnique technique, Vector3 cameraPosition,
        Matrix world, Matrix viewProjection, LightList lights)
    {
        if (gd == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("gd");
        }

        // get model bones
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(bones);

        BlendState bs = gd.BlendState;
        DepthStencilState ds = gd.DepthStencilState;

        gd.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;
        gd.BlendState = BlendState.Additive;


        // for each mesh in model
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            // get mesh world matrix
            Matrix worldBone = bones[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * world;
            Matrix worldBoneInverse = Matrix.Invert(worldBone);

            // compute camera position in object space
            Vector3 cameraObjectSpace = cameraPosition - worldBone.Translation;
            cameraObjectSpace = Vector3.TransformNormal(cameraObjectSpace,
                                                    worldBoneInverse);

            gd.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;

            // for each mesh part
            foreach (ModelMeshPart meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                // if primitives to render
                if (meshPart.PrimitiveCount > 0)
                {
                    // setup vertices and indices
                    gd.SetVertexBuffer(meshPart.VertexBuffer);
                    gd.Indices = meshPart.IndexBuffer;

                    // setup effect
                    Effect effect = meshPart.Effect;
                    effect.Parameters["WorldViewProj"].SetValue(worldBone * viewProjection);
                    effect.Parameters["CameraPosition"].SetValue(cameraObjectSpace);

                    // setup technique
                    effect.CurrentTechnique =
                        meshPart.Effect.Techniques[(int)technique];


                    // if not lights specified
                    if (lights == null)
                    {
                        // begin effect
                        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
                        // draw with plain mapping
                        gd.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                            meshPart.VertexOffset, 0, meshPart.NumVertices,
                            meshPart.StartIndex, meshPart.PrimitiveCount);
                        gd.SetVertexBuffer(null);
                        gd.Indices = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gd.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
                        gd.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;

                        // get light effect parameters
                        EffectParameter effectLightPosition =
                                            effect.Parameters[1];
                        EffectParameter effectLightColor =
                                            effect.Parameters[2];
                        EffectParameter effectLightAmbient =
                                            effect.Parameters[3];

                        // ambient light
                        Vector3 ambient = lights.ambient;

                        // for each light
                        foreach (Light light in lights.lights)
                        {
                            // setup light in effect
                            effectLightAmbient.SetValue(ambient);
                            light.SetEffect(effectLightPosition,
                                effectLightColor, worldBoneInverse);

                            // begin effect
                            effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
                            // draw primitives
                            gd.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                                meshPart.VertexOffset, 0, meshPart.NumVertices,
                                meshPart.StartIndex, meshPart.PrimitiveCount);

                            // setup additive blending with no depth write
                            gd.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.DepthRead;
                            gd.BlendState = BlendState.Additive;

                            // clear ambinet light (applied in first pass only)
                            ambient = Vector3.Zero;
                        }

                        // clear vertices and indices
                        gd.SetVertexBuffer(null);
                        gd.Indices = null;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        gd.DepthStencilState = ds;
        gd.BlendState = bs;
    }
```

And here is the shader I'm using:

```
float4x4 WorldViewProj;
float4 LightPosition;
float3 LightColor;
float3 LightAmbient;
float3 CameraPosition;

texture2D Texture;
sampler2D TextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Texture>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
};
sampler2D TextureSamplerClamp = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Texture>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
    AddressU = clamp;
    AddressV = clamp;
};

texture2D Bump0;
sampler2D NormalSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Bump0>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
};

texture2D Specular0;
sampler2D SpecularSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Specular0>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
};

texture2D Emissive0;
sampler2D GlowMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Emissive0>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
};

textureCUBE Reflect;
samplerCUBE ReflectSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Reflect>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
    AddressU = clamp;
    AddressV = clamp;
    AddressW = clamp;
};

void PlainMappingVS( 
     in float4 InPosition    : POSITION0,
     in float2 InTexCoord    : TEXCOORD0,
    out float4 OutPosition    : POSITION0,
    out float2 OutTexCoord    : TEXCOORD0 )
{
    OutPosition = mul(InPosition, WorldViewProj);
    OutTexCoord = InTexCoord;
}

float4 PlainMappingPS( in float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0 ) : COLOR0
{
    return tex2D(TextureSampler, TexCoord);
}

void NormalMappingVS( 
     in float4 InPosition    : POSITION0,
     in float2 InTexCoord    : TEXCOORD0,
     in float3 InNormal      : NORMAL0,  
     in float3 InBinormal    : BINORMAL0,
     in float3 InTangent     : TANGENT0,
    out float4 OutPosition   : POSITION0,
    out float2 OutTexCoord   : TEXCOORD0,
    out float3 OutLightDir   : TEXCOORD1,
    out float3 OutViewDir    : TEXCOORD2,
    out float3 OutReflectDir : TEXCOORD3 )
{
    OutPosition = mul(InPosition, WorldViewProj);

    OutTexCoord = InTexCoord;

    float3x3 tangent_space = float3x3(InTangent, InBinormal, InNormal);

    OutLightDir = mul(tangent_space, LightPosition.xyz - InPosition.xyz);

    OutViewDir = mul(tangent_space, CameraPosition - InPosition.xyz);

    OutReflectDir = reflect(InPosition.xyz - CameraPosition, InNormal);
}

float4 NormalMappingPS(
    in float2 TexCoord        : TEXCOORD0,
    in float3 LightDir        : TEXCOORD1,
    in float3 ViewDir         : TEXCOORD2,
    in float3 ReflectDir      : TEXCOORD3 ) : COLOR0
{
    float4 diffuse = tex2D(TextureSampler, TexCoord);
    float4 specular = tex2D(SpecularSampler, TexCoord);
    float4 normal = tex2D(NormalSampler, TexCoord);
    float3 reflect = texCUBE(ReflectSampler, ReflectDir);
    float4 glow = tex2D(GlowMapSampler, TexCoord);

    float3 n = normalize(normal.xyz - 0.5);
    float3 l = normalize(LightDir);
    float3 v = normalize(ViewDir);
    float3 h = normalize(l+v);

    float ndotl = saturate(dot(n,l));
    float ndoth = saturate(dot(n,h));
    if (ndotl == 0)    ndoth = 0;

    float3 ambient = LightAmbient * diffuse.xyz;

    specular.xyz *= LightColor * pow(ndoth, specular.w * 255);
    diffuse.xyz *= LightColor * ndotl;
    reflect *= 1 - normal.w;

    float glow_intensity = saturate(dot(glow.xyz, 1.0) + dot(specular.xyz, 1.0));

    float4 color;
    color.xyz = ambient + glow.xyz + diffuse.xyz + specular.xyz + reflect.xyz;
    color.w = glow_intensity;

    return color;
}

void ViewMappingVS( 
     in float4 InPosition   : POSITION0,
     in float3 InNormal     : NORMAL0,  
    out float4 OutPosition  : POSITION0,
    out float  OutFacing    : TEXCOORD0 )
{
    OutPosition = mul(InPosition, WorldViewProj);

    float3 view = normalize(CameraPosition - InPosition.xyz);

    OutFacing = saturate(dot(view, InNormal));
}

float4 ViewMappingPS(in float Facing : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    Facing *= Facing;
    Facing *= Facing;

    float4 tex = tex2D(TextureSamplerClamp, float2(Facing, 0));
    tex.w = 1.0f;

    return tex;
}

Technique PlainMapping
{
    Pass
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 PlainMappingVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PlainMappingPS();
    }
}

Technique NormalMapping
{
    Pass
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 NormalMappingVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 NormalMappingPS();
    }
}

Technique ViewMapping
{
    Pass
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_1_1 ViewMappingVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 ViewMappingPS();
    }
}
```

But two things don't go as I would like them to. First, I would like to tile the texture as the box increases in size. And second the lighting on it seems to go all wonky. I'm using the Normal Lighting from the Ship Game in the education catalog.

Any ideas what's going on with the lighting? Or how I might go about tiling the textures?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313388/xna-tiling-a-2d-texutre-to-fill-a-rectangle explains how to tile a texture in XNA

Comment: @Patashu That is for 2D rendering with `SpriteBatch` - it doesn't apply to 3D (except for the use of `LinearWrap` - but the question here already has that).

Comment: As for the question, I'd probably use a vertex shader to apply an appropriate transform to either the input texture coordinates or scaled-only vertex positions to get correctly scaled texture coordinates. Sorry I'm not in a position to write up a full answer for this at the moment. As for your lightning: are your normals being scaled? Scaling and normals don't mix well.

Comment: So there is the world matrix, projection matrix, and normals. Normals are used to take the model from "model space" and put it in front of the projection matrix, right? If that is correct, then my normals are not scaled. If I indeed am right with what normals are...

Comment: I've added the shader code I'm using.