# XNA - Repeat texture x amount of times

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have a basic brick texture that I want to repeat across the X axis a certain number of times. Instead of drawing (possibly) hundreds of the same texture using `spriteBatch.Draw(...)` over and over, is there any easier way like `spriteBatch.Draw(brick,vector_array[],color)` where `brick` is the texture and `vector_array[]` would be all of my vector points for the texture to be painted over and over?

Unrelated to that idea, my next best idea was to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 16; i += 1)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(brick, brickXY, Color.White);
                brickXY.X += 32;
            }
```

which would hopefully draw 16 brick textures repeatedly to the right. (Each texture is 32x32) It *does* do this but it only stays on screen for one frame. How could I fix this?

Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the BrickXY somewhere else.
You are setting the BrickXY alone but its a array so it needs to be like
BrickXY[int]
try something like:

```
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        brick = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Whatever texture you want here");
        (int a = 0; a < brickXY.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            brickXY[a].X += (32 * a);
        }
    }
```

After that all of the values are set then draw them or else the bricks will start to move.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        for (int i = 0; i <= brickXY.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(brick, brickXY[i], Color.White);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This totally worked. I don't really understand why my method of the for loop wasn't working but this does the job just fine.

Comment: You can actually do this without multiple draw calls.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313388/xna-tiling-a-2d-texutre-to-fill-a-rectangle).